# How to disable F11 in windows 10/Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Windows is being too helpful. When I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, my console goes full screen.
I wish to disable this for the following reason.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadKey(true);
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(
                String.Format(input.Key.ToString()));
                string lockedDiceInput = Convert.ToString(input.Key);
                //yes I should make a method for this but later
                switch (lockedDiceInput)
                {
                    case "F1":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[0]);
                        break;
                    case "F2":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[1]);
                        break;
                    case "F3":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[2]);
                        break;
                    case "F4":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[3]);
                        break;
                    case "F5":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[4]);
                        break;
                    case "F6":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[5]);
                        break;
                    case "F7":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[6]);
                        break;
                    case "F8":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[7]);
                        break;
                    case "F9":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[8]);
                        break;
                    case "F10":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[9]);
                        break;
                        // Not working
                    case "F11":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[10]);
                        break;
                    case "F12":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[11]);
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigning score to {0}", targetsSheetArray[12]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //TODO
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        }
```

Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> will not trigger case 'F11', the console will go full screen instead. How do I turn off this 'feature'? I'm okay with modifying my console application as well with tweaking my OS (Windows 10).

Similar question found but it was unanswered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613256/change-f11-to-not-open-fullscreen-in-visual-studio-2015)).

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pressing F11 will not trigger case 'F11', the console will go full screen instead. How do I turn off this 'feature'?

You can disable the "full screen" feature by editing the registry key,
Type "regedit" in the cmd prompt, go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Console, change the ForceV2 value from '1' to '0'.

Answer (score 1):

To disable Windows intercepting F11 (which would otherwise toggle Full-screen) call SetConsoleMode and pass mode flags with ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT bit cleared:

```
DWORD previousMode; // typically(?) 0x1f7
GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &previousMode);
auto newMode = previousMode & (~ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), newMode);
```

Then, pressing F1 causes _getch to return 224 followed by 133 as you'd expect, without the window going full-screen.

Similarly, for .NET

```
    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);


    var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(handle, out var previousMode);

    var newMode = previousMode & (~ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
    
    SetConsoleMode(handle, newMode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complete the answer provided by @Jackie concerning what is hidden behing the register HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Console>ForceV2.

It looks like that to change this value from 1 to 0 will activate the use of the "legacy console mode" by default in all the windows managed by the console host (the underlying code that supports all character-mode applications including the Windows command prompt, the Windows PowerShell prompt, and others).

I don't know all the details of this mode but it will avoid those windows to be freely resized and the F11 keyboard key will not pass the window in fullscreen.

The "legacy console mode" can also be accessed directly with a right click on the title-bar of the console window where you can check the related box.

[Legacy_console_mode_checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNL5.png)

For more details, take a look to the following links :

- [What's New in the Windows Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/mt427362(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Legacy Console mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/legacymode)